# Failed to bind to: spark-master, using a remote cluster with two workers

Tags: binding, apache-spark, runtime-error

I am managing to get everything working with the local master and two remote workers. Now, I want to connect to a remote master that has the same remote workers. I have tried different combinations of settings withing the /etc/hosts and other reccomendations on the Internet, but NOTHING worked.

The Main class is:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ScalaInterface sInterface = new ScalaInterface(CHUNK_SIZE,
            "awsAccessKeyId",
            "awsSecretAccessKey");

    SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("POC_JAVA_AND_SPARK")
            .setMaster("spark://spark-master:7077");

    org.apache.spark.SparkContext sc = new org.apache.spark.SparkContext(
            conf);

    sInterface.enableS3Connection(sc);
    org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD<Tuple2<Path, Text>> fileAndLine = (RDD<Tuple2<Path, Text>>) sInterface.getMappedRDD(sc, "s3n://somebucket/");

    org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD<String> pInfo = (RDD<String>) sInterface.mapPartitionsWithIndex(fileAndLine);

    JavaRDD<String> pInfoJ = pInfo.toJavaRDD();

    List<String> result = pInfoJ.collect();

    String miscInfo = sInterface.getMiscInfo(sc, pInfo);

    System.out.println(miscInfo);

}
```

It fails at:

```
List<String> result = pInfoJ.collect();
```

The error I am getting is:

```
1354 [sparkDriver-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] ERROR akka.remote.transport.netty.NettyTransport  - failed to bind to spark-master/192.168.0.191:0, shutting down Netty transport
1354 [main] WARN  org.apache.spark.util.Utils  - Service 'sparkDriver' could not bind on port 0. Attempting port 1.
1355 [main] DEBUG org.apache.spark.util.AkkaUtils  - In createActorSystem, requireCookie is: off
1363 [sparkDriver-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] INFO  akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider$RemotingTerminator  - Shutting down remote daemon.
1364 [sparkDriver-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] INFO  akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider$RemotingTerminator  - Remote daemon shut down; proceeding with flushing remote transports.
1364 [sparkDriver-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-5] INFO  akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider$RemotingTerminator  - Remoting shut down.
1367 [sparkDriver-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] INFO  akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger  - Slf4jLogger started
1370 [sparkDriver-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6] INFO  Remoting  - Starting remoting
1380 [sparkDriver-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] ERROR akka.remote.transport.netty.NettyTransport  - failed to bind to spark-master/192.168.0.191:0, shutting down Netty transport
Exception in thread "main" 1382 [sparkDriver-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6] INFO  akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider$RemotingTerminator  - Shutting down remote daemon.
1382 [sparkDriver-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6] INFO  akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider$RemotingTerminator  - Remote daemon shut down; proceeding with flushing remote transports.
java.net.BindException: Failed to bind to: spark-master/192.168.0.191:0: Service 'sparkDriver' failed after 16 retries!
    at org.jboss.netty.bootstrap.ServerBootstrap.bind(ServerBootstrap.java:272)
    at akka.remote.transport.netty.NettyTransport$$anonfun$listen$1.apply(NettyTransport.scala:393)
    at akka.remote.transport.netty.NettyTransport$$anonfun$listen$1.apply(NettyTransport.scala:389)
    at scala.util.Success$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Try.scala:206)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:161)
    at scala.util.Success.map(Try.scala:206)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Future.scala:235)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Future.scala:235)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:32)
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$Batch$$anonfun$run$1.processBatch$1(BatchingExecutor.scala:67)
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$Batch$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(BatchingExecutor.scala:82)
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$Batch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(BatchingExecutor.scala:59)
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$Batch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(BatchingExecutor.scala:59)
    at scala.concurrent.BlockContext$.withBlockContext(BlockContext.scala:72)
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$Batch.run(BatchingExecutor.scala:58)
    at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:41)
    at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:393)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
1383 [sparkDriver-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-7] INFO  akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider$RemotingTerminator  - Remoting shut down.
1385 [delete Spark temp dirs] DEBUG org.apache.spark.util.Utils  - Shutdown hook called
```

Thank you kindly for your help!

Comment: none of the answers here helped me, however to my surprise turning the wifi connection off did solve it for me. That is actually one of those annoying workaround though!

Answer (score 55):

Setting the environment variable SPARK_LOCAL_IP=127.0.0.1 solved this for me.

Comment: This solves the issue for me too. But it was because of ipv6 on the laptop

Answer (score 12):

I had this problem when my `/etc/hosts` file was mapping the wrong IP address to my local hostname.

The `BindException` in your logs complains about the IP address `192.168.0.191`. I assume that resolves to the hostname of your machine and it's *not* the actual IP address that your network interface is using. It should work fine once you fix that.

Answer (score 5):

I had spark working in my EC2 instance. I started a new web server and to meet its requirement I had to change hostname to ec2 public DNS name i.e.

```
hostname ec2-54-xxx-xxx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com
```

After that my spark could not work and showed error as below:

> 16/09/20 21:02:22 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkDriver' could not bind on port 0. Attempting port 1.
>   16/09/20 21:02:22 ERROR SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.

I solve it by setting SPARK_LOCAL_IP to as below:

```
export SPARK_LOCAL_IP="localhost"
```

then just launched sparkling shell as below:

```
$SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-shell
```

Comment: It has been a long time ago I posted this question, I guess that some things got changed in the meantime to make simple solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Possily your master is running on non-default port. Can you post your submit command? 
Have a look in https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/spark-standalone.html#connecting-an-application-to-the-cluster

Comment: I am not using a submit, I want to achieve it with IDE. Submit works fine, and Master is set as spark://spark-master:7077

Comment: The way I do from IDE is to create a conf object and set master through setMaster method. Then I create spark context using the conf object. I believe spark context is the link between application and cluster

Comment: This is exactly the way I do it, and exactly how I got the mentioned error.

Comment: No due to licensing. I can post the Main class however.