# Access Apache Spark Standalone Master via IP

Tags: deployment, apache-spark

I try to connect to my Apache Spark Master via Java, but by providing the IP:

This is my code for creating the `SparkConf`:

```
return new SparkConf()
    .setAppName(appName)
    .setMaster(master)
    .setJars(jars)
    .set("spark.serializer",
            "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer");
```

I want to provide as master spark://IP:PORT. Unfourtunately this doesn't seem to work. It only works with hostnames (e.g. spark://MyMacbook:7077), not with IPs (e.g. spark://127.0.0.1:7077). Is it possible to start the master in a way that it also accepts requests via IP?

I need this since i'm creating a quite complex setup via Docker and want to access the Master externally (at first just for testing purposes).

EDIT:
I checked the Master console now and it states:

```
dropping message [class akka.actor.ActorSelectionMessage] for non-local recipient [Actor[akka.tcp://sparkMaster@192.168.99.100:7077/]] arriving at [akka.tcp://sparkMaster@192.168.99.100:7077] inbound addresses are [akka.tcp://sparkMaster@spark-master:7077]
```

So we can see that Akka drops the message, because it was sent to the IP (192.168.99.100) instead of the hostname (spark-master). But I want to use the IP... also providing `-h 192.168.99.100` as master start parameters would not work in my case (since using Docker and 192.168.99.100 is the machine IP).

Isn't it possible to define multiple hostnames or at least accept all requests?

EDIT:
The issue is STILL unsolved, but I found another point where this problem occurs. When I try to launch the Spark Standalone Master and bind it to the public IP (in case of my docker 192.168.99.100) then I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.BindException: Failed to bind to: /192.168.99.100:7093: Service 'sparkMaster' failed after 16 retries!
at org.jboss.netty.bootstrap.ServerBootstrap.bind(ServerBootstrap.java:272)
at akka.remote.transport.netty.NettyTransport$$anonfun$listen$1.apply(NettyTransport.scala:393)
at akka.remote.transport.netty.NettyTransport$$anonfun$listen$1.apply(NettyTransport.scala:389)
at scala.util.Success$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Try.scala:206)
at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:161)
at scala.util.Success.map(Try.scala:206)
at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Future.scala:235)
at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Future.scala:235)
at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:32)
at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$AbstractBatch.processBatch(BatchingExecutor.scala:55)
at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(BatchingExecutor.scala:91)
at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(BatchingExecutor.scala:91)
at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(BatchingExecutor.scala:91)
at scala.concurrent.BlockContext$.withBlockContext(BlockContext.scala:72)
at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch.run(BatchingExecutor.scala:90)
at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:40)
at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:397)
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
```

This issue is related (/ the same?) to the (unanswered question of Wayne Song):
[Getting java.net.BindException when attempting to start Spark master on EC2 node with public IP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31659228/getting-java-net-bindexception-when-attempting-to-start-spark-master-on-ec2-node)