# Getting BindException on new download of Spark on Mac OS X 10.12.3 (Sierra)

Tags: apache-spark

I recently downloaded Spark on my home iMac running Mac OS X 10.12.3 (Sierra) and went to run the examples but immediately
 hit a set of stack traces:

```
17/02/15 18:07:48 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkDriver' could not bind on port 0. Attempting port 1.
17/02/15 18:07:48 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkDriver' could not bind on port 0. Attempting port 1.
...
java.net.BindException: Can't assign requested address: Service 'sparkDriver' failed after 16 retries (starting from 0)! Consider explicitly setting the appropriate port for the service 'sparkDriver' (for example spark.ui.port for SparkUI) to an available port or increasing spark.port.maxRetries.
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
...
<console>:14: error: not found: value spark
   import spark.implicits._
...
```

Searching for a hit for the BindException turned up no matches to my exact problem.  But the following stack overflow question and answer had an interesting [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29906686/failed-to-bind-to-spark-master-using-a-remote-cluster-with-two-workers)

I tried what the top answer suggested:

```
export SPARK_LOCAL_IP=127.0.0.1
```

This worked perfectly.

Is it legal in Stack Overflow to ask and answer your own question?  I wanted to simply leave a comment over at the other question about my particular case to let others know what helps, but I'm new to Stack Overflow with this particular account and don't have the 50 reputation required to add a comment.

Comment: yes you can answer your own questions, go ahead, btw pls provide info how did you installed spark: binary, pip etc

Comment: You can answer your own question, but there's no point if it's a duplicate of another question. Voting up an answer is how you tell others it's useful.